# Multiclass classification of timeseries data using NN

Tags: neural-network

I have the following dataset that I was thinking of using RNN/LSTM for classifying the protocol. Data contains features from packet capture that has only two provided fields: OUI of the MAC address of the device and the inter-arrival time (IAT) of the packets for a specific protocol.

For example, the labeled data for http and ntp from the point-of-view of a specific device type is provided below:

```
# MAC, ConnectivityIAT  -> protocol     
ff:f1:f2, 10, -> http
ff:f1:f2, 20, -> http
ff:f1:f2, 30, -> http
ff:f1:f2, 0, -> http

ff:f1:f2, 3, -> ntp
ff:f1:f2, 6, -> ntp
ff:f1:f2, 9, -> ntp
```

The task is to predict the correct class when something like:

```
ff:ff1:f2, 10 -> ?
```

is seen.

Questions:

- How do I convert the categorical value of OUI to numerical entities
- How to approch the solution using a NN ?

Comment: What is the OUI here? Is it `ff` or something different?

Comment: From the sample data, this looks like a binary classification problem  to me.

Answer (score 1):

**How to approach the solution using a NN ?**

Given your data, it doesn't look like an RNN/LSTM is the most sensible choice.

It looks like you have two features and a binary output. RNN/LSTM are useful with variable-length input, otherwise, they are a bit overkill.

Also, make sure that you have a reasonable amount of data before using a deep learning approach. They usually have many parameters to train, and if you don't have enough data points, this might be difficult to do.

If you want to stick to NN, I'd say a regular multilayer perceptron might do the job. If you are open to other options, I would try decision trees for this particular problem.

**How do I convert the categorical value of OUI to numerical entities**

You could use one-hot encoding. There are plenty of implementations out there (i.e. [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)), or you could do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the categorical value of OUI using a [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). It looks like you have two features (OUI and IAT) and a fixed number of classes / outputs. You could use an MLP classifier to solve this problem. In Keras:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(num_features,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is just an example, it's better to create a deeper architecture and add regularization (e.g. l1/l2 weight penalty or drop-out) to prevent over-fitting.